# heroku:db push is not working, time zone displacement out of range

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, heroku, taps, heroku-toolbelt

I cannot seem to push using heroku, **heroku db:pull works fine** but **not heroku db:push**

here is the error i get

> Taps Server Error: PGError: ERROR:  time zone displacement out of range

my gemfile

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.2.11'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'kaminari'
gem 'bootstrap-kaminari-views'

gem 'devise'

gem 'pg'

gem 'rmagick'
gem 'carrierwave'
gem 'fog', '~> 1.3.1'

group :development do
  gem 'taps'
  gem 'sequel'
  gem 'sqlite3'
  gem 'pry'
end

group :assets do
  gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 2.2.1.1'
  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'
  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
end
```

I am using `ruby-1.9.3-p327`, I have also tried installing `ruby-1.9.2-p318` using rvm but it does not work either, it has the same time zone error as before

---

I have also tried using [heroku's pgbackups](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgres-import-export) to dump my local database upload it to s3 and then restore from there to heroku, but to no avail.

---

#### The commands i have used for pgbackups are

```
PGPASSWORD=mypassword pg_dump -Fc --no-acl --no-owner -h localhost -U myuser mydb > mydb.dump
```

Then i copied it to my s3 bucket and made it public

And restored it from s3 to heroku db using

```
heroku pgbackups:restore DATABASE 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/my_bucket/my_db.dump'
```

here is the error from pgbackups

```
2013-01-23T19:19:23+00:00 app[pgbackups]: psql: bin//psql-9.2.1-64bit
2013-01-23T19:19:23+00:00 app[pgbackups]: pv: bin//pv-1.1.4-64bit
2013-01-23T19:19:23+00:00 app[pgbackups]:       SELECT count(*) = 0 as is_empty
2013-01-23T19:19:23+00:00 app[pgbackups]:       FROM pg_class INNER JOIN pg_roles ON relowner = pg_roles.oid
2013-01-23T19:19:23+00:00 app[pgbackups]:       WHERE rolname <> '\''postgres'\'''
2013-01-23T19:19:44+00:00 app[pgbackups]: psql-9.2.1-64bit: could not connect to server: Connection timed out
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### It now works using ruby-1.9.2-p318 after removing heroku-toolbelt

Here is what I did (Ubuntu 12.04)

---

#### 1. Remove heroku toolbelt

```
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/heroku
sudo rm -rf /usr/bin/heroku
```

---

#### 2. Update gemfile

I added require false to taps

```
group :development do
  gem 'taps', :require => false
end
```

and also add the heroku gem if you dont have it in your gemfile already

```
gem 'heroku'
```

---

#### 3. Install ruby 1.9.2 and gems

Navigate to your app (cd ~/sites/myapp) and do

```
rvm install ruby-1.9.2-p318
rvm use ruby-1.9.2-p318
bundle install
gem install rb-readline
```

You should now have the heroku gem installed
To double check run this in console
`ls ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems`

You should now see a folder called heroku with a version appended to it. eg. *heroku-2.26.3*

---

#### 4. Run that push again

Now you should still be in your app folder eg (~/sites/myapp)
Try the push using the heroku gem you have just installed, **remember to change your version** if you have downloaded a diffirent one.

```
~/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/heroku-2.26.3/bin/heroku db:push
```

it seems you need to switch back to ruby 1.9.3 to use rake db:migrate ect

error i got when using rake db:migrate

```
You're running a version of ruby with no Readline support
Please `gem install rb-readline` or recompile ruby --with-readline.
```

```
rvm use ruby-1.9.3-p327
```

and you should be on your way!

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this discussion:
https://github.com/ricardochimal/taps/issues/93